# Trying to move from babel to swc for my nextjs project and it throws error "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled"

Tags: next.js, swc-compiler

I am trying to move from babel to swc for my NextJS project(NextJS version 13). Here is my bablerc file. I keep getting error "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled". Is there a guide on the migration somewhere?

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "react-intl-auto",
      {
        "removePrefix": "src/",
        "filebase": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "babel-plugin-import",
      {
        "libraryName": "@mui/material",
        "libraryDirectory": "src",
        "camel2DashComponentName": false
      },
      "core"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I created an .swcrc file and it did not help

```
   {
      "jsc": {
        "parser": {
          "syntax": "ecmascript",
          "jsx": true
        }
      }
}
```

It tells me *Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation*. But I am not using babel and need to achieve this using SWC